# Is there a way of avoding diamond kind problems this OO Design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, class-design, object-oriented-analysis

I have an event processing use case where I am using templates for various kinds of logic involved during event processing e.g transaction handling, processing template based on events e.g update, insert, etc. however, there is some common processing logic on concrete implementation as well which is currently creating diamond problems. Is there a better way to model them?

```
AbstractEventProcessing (batch processing, txn handling etc with construction deps)
^
|
|-------|------------------------------| 
|       UpdateEventProcessing          InsertEventProcessing
|       (template for processing, no construction deps)
|
|----------------------------|
AbstractEvent1Processor      AbstractEvent2Processor
(parsing for event1 etc.)    ...
constrcution deps            ^
^                            |
|                            ConceretUpdateEvent2Processor
|                            (needs UpdateEventProcessing) 
|
|-------------------------------|           
ConcreteUpdateEvent1Processor   ConcreteInsertEvent1Processor   
(needs UpdateEventProcessing)
```

However, the template is the same for Update and Insert for all the Event processors which lead to problems of having 2 base class (AbstractEvent1Processor & UpdateEventProcessing). Is there are some other ways of modeling these? Also, since these templates are used in many concrete implementations how do not repeat testing the same things at different places

Comment: I suspect you should be using composition, not inheritance.  An easy test of whether inheritance is appropriate is:  Is polymorphism needed here?  Does the type `AbstractEvent1Processor` appear anywhere in other classes, other than after the `extends` keyword?  If the answer is no, you should not be using inheritance.  The common code should be in a separate class which each of the processor classes can instantiate as needed.  In general, inheritance should not be used solely to share code.

Comment: @VGR thanks. yes, `AbstractEvent1Processor` doesn't get used in other forms, it just has some implementations for the abstract methods coming from the top and is being shared with concrete classes for the same type of event. Along similar lines what are your thoughts on having inheritance with templates which get refined by every level like in above e.g we have `process` which is then enriched by an update or delete? is the inheritance fine here provided they may also need some construction dependencies as well

Comment: I stand by my view that inheritance should not be used unless polymorphism is needed.  For example, if AbstractEvent1Processor had an inheritable method called `formatEvent`, I would move it out of AbstractEvent1Processor into a separate class called `EventFormatter`, which each of the processor classes could freely instantiate and use without depending on an inheritance hierarchy.